# Word for when someone was being sent back and forth between lots of places to get something done

Tags: single-word-requests

Like when your Bulgarian national insurance record gets corrupted and, now, you need to prove that you didn't earn 500,000 USD back in 2001...
So you go to NOI, who tell you to go to MVR-IP, who tell you the case is actually with NAP, who tell you everything looks fine, this is a NOI problem, so go to them...

I can put some slangy words in context but they aren't as precise as I would like:
She got *rattled around* all the sections of the IT department until someone agreed to take a look at her computer

Ideally, a words that not so slangy but rather more literally meaning what I am trying to describe above :)

Comment: There is also "wild-goose chase" https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wild-goose_chase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being **given the go-around** or **run-around**.

From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-around):

> go-around *noun*
>
> 1: runaround: *gave me the go-around*

and

[again M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/runaround):

> runaround *noun*
>
> 1: deceptive or delaying action especially in response to a request: 
>   *tired of getting the runaround*

[An example from the internet {hotel reviews}](https://www.expedia.com/Kapalua-Hotels-The-Ritz-Carlton.h3390-p127.Hotel-Reviews) (there are surprisingly few for 'go around'):

> I asked for a page to be printed and was given the go around for 15
>   minutes, and then finally told that a manager on break would have to
>   print it for me....

And one quoted in [the Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+around) for 'run around':

> Australian police are given the run around by a kangaroo in Melbourne.

Open, hyphenated, and (for 'runaround') closed forms are all used.

Answer (score 1):

Being sent **from pillar to post** means, according to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/from-pillar-to-post):

> from one predicament, place of appeal, etc. to another, usually under harassment

Some examples from the same link:

> After being bandied from pillar to post for about twenty minutes, she finally got connected to a Voice.
>
> Countess, if I knew that I wouldn't have spent the last day wandering from pillar to post searching for her.

[Here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/running-from-pillar-to-post.3146525/) someone even says of this phrase:

> The expression is "He was sent from pillar to post".
>
> [...]
>
> It means "to be subjected to endless bureaucracy".

And their example sentence (from the same link):

> "He was sent from pillar to post. To get his permit he had to go to the police station, the post office, the market office, the health centre, the town hall and back to the police station. There was a form to complete in every office."